# client passing json to server in webservice jersey(without maven)

Tags: java, json, rest

I am trying to pass json to my web-service from a client program(WebService created as webapplication).Client program is written in core java.Based on  http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/  tutorial i wrote my client program.I need to know how to run my program.(Using JERSEY NOT MAVEN).At the time without client i hardcode json and getting fine responses.But in this case while adding client,the client program contains main() method and i am confused and need to know how to run it.I will put my code for further understanding.Can anyone provide a documentation regarding my dobt?I am new to this enviornment...

Postjson.java

```
public class Postjson {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("inside postjson classfor posting request");
             try {
//               Student st = new Student("Adriana", "Barrer", 12, 9);
Clientdetails cld=new Clientdetails("request","AuthenticationType","test@gmail.com",12345,"null","null");
//               String JSON_DATA =
//                       "{" 
//                         + "  \"SnapshotRequest\": [" 
//                         + "    {" 
//                         + "      \"AuthenticationType\": \"email\"," 
//                         + "      \"EmailAddress\": \"test@gmail.com\","                  
//                         + "      \"Password\" : \"12345\"," 
//                         + "      \"PracticeID\" : \"null\"," 
//                         + "      \"DeviceID\" : \"null\""
//                         + "    } +   ]"
//                     + "}";
//                Clientdetails cld=new Clientdetails();
//                cld.setUsername("test@gmail.com");
//                cld.setPassword("password");
//                cld.setDevice_id("12345");
//                           Student st = new Student("Adriana", "Barrer", 12, 9);
                                ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
                                clientConfig.getFeatures().put(
                 JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
                                Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
                 WebResource webResource = client
                 .resource("http://localhost:9090/Snapshothealthapp1/rest/customers/get");
                 System.out.println("after url step");
                 ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                         .type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, cld);
                 System.out.println("after passing json object");
                 if (response.getStatus() != 200) {

                                 throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "

                                         + response.getStatus());

                             }



                             String output = response.getEntity(String.class);



                             System.out.println("Server response .... \n");

                             System.out.println(output);



                         } catch (Exception e) {



                             e.printStackTrace();



                         }

        }
```

Authentication.java

```
   import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    import com.snapshothealthapp1.client.Clientdetails;
    import com.snapshothealthapp1.model.AuthenticationModel;
    @Path("/customers")
    public class Authentication {
        @POST
        @Path("/get")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getRequestUrl(Clientdetails s) {
            //TODO:Create a JSON(recieved from client request)
    //      JSONObject jsonClient = new JSONObject(); 
            System.out.println("inside Authentication");

             String output = s.toString();

             return Response.status(201).entity(output).build();
        }
```

web.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>

     <init-param>

      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.snapshothealthapp1.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>

        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>

        <param-value>true</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

How to run a single project with main method and another resource method.If it is not possible please tell an auxillarymethod todo it?
I kept my server on and run the main method(client code) .but it gives me error.
error is posted below

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.snapshothealthapp1.client.Clientdetails, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:563)
    at com.snapshothealthapp1.client.Postjson.main(Postjson.java:40)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.snapshothealthapp1.client.Clientdetails, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:204)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
    ... 5 more
```

As i new to this field i am getting confused about is this way correct or not.Can anybody please help me.Any helpwill be highly appreciable....

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tutorial you linked to, it is using this Maven dependency for JSON/POJO support.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency pulls in a bunch of other dependencies (that's why we use Maven :-)

So you need to make sure to have all the below jars

[image]

You can search for and download [them here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json)

Everything else you have looks fine.